# Wordpress: add a class to a div using add_filter function

Tags: wordpress

I've previously used the `add_filter()` function to add a class to the body like so:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_custom_class' );
function add_custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $classes[] = 'post';
        }
    return $classes;
}
```

I'd like to be able to use something along these lines to add a class to a div:

```
add_filter( 'div_class', 'add_custom_class' );
function add_custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $classes[] = 'post';
        }
    return $classes;
}
```

or better still:

```
add_filter( 'div_class', 'add_custom_class' );
function add_custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $classes[] = 'post';
        }
    else if ( is_singular( 'custom-post-type' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-post-type-class';
        }
    return $classes;
}
```

And then pull in the class in my theme like so:

```
<div class="wrapper <?php echo div_class(); ?>">
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

```
function so50582899_div_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    if(is_single()) {
        $classes[] = 'single-post';
    } elseif(is_page()) {
        $classes[] = 'page'
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'so50582899_div_class');
```

Then you can call it like `<div class="<?php post_class(); ?>">`

**EDIT:** To remove all existing classes add `$classes = array();` to the top of the function. This will reset the classes that are returned and only return the ones you set within the function.

So it would end up like:

```
function so50582899_div_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    $classes = array();

    if(is_single()) {
        $classes[] = 'single-post';
    } elseif(is_page()) {
        $classes[] = 'page'
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'so50582899_div_class');
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters

Comment: Hey - looks like it outputs something close to what I need but I get a lot of extra unnecessary classes along for the ride, for example: `class="post-3742 work type-work status-publish hentry single-post"`. 

Is it possible to strip out the extra stuff and just have the desired class?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, please see my updated answer. If this works for you, feel free to accept it as the answer :)